# What does ± times ± equal?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

What does ± times ± equal as we know that - * - = + and + * + = + ? I'm sorry for this layman question I'm purely curious. Thanks.

Comment: I think that's not defined

Comment: Long story short: it depends what you mean. A phrase with multiple $\pm$s is generally ambiguous.

Comment: My guess is that ± * ± = ±

Comment: Indeed, if $\pm$ times $\pm$ involves four possibilities, the result is $\pm$, while if it involves only two, the result is $+$. Both are possible options, only context can tell.

Answer (score 3):

A symbol as $\pm 1$ is well defined and means $(+1) \;or \;(-1)$.  But if we write $(\pm 1) \cdot (\pm 1)$ this is not so well defined and the result is dependent on the order in wich we interpret the possible products.

We can use a  ''no order intrpretation'', so that $(\pm 1)\cdot (\pm 1)=(\pm1)\cdot (+1) \;or\;(\pm 1)\cdot(-1)$ so that the result is $\pm 1$.

Or we can ''fix the order'' in the sense that the we interpret $\pm 1$ as an ordered couple $(+1,-1)$ and we perform the multiplication between corrsepondign elements of the couple. In this case we have $(\pm 1)\cdot (\pm 1)=+1$. This interpretation can be suggested in a context where is used also the symbol $\mp$, so that we have  $(\pm 1)\cdot(\mp 1)=-1$

But in general I think that it is better to avoid the use of multple $\pm$ in an expression.

Comment: One solution is to instead use a symbol like $\xi$ to instead of $\pm$, with the understanding that $\xi^2=1$. The advantage is that, if you have independent $\pm$ ambiguities (as one would, say, in finding roots of a polynomials that's quadratic in $x^2$) then one can simply include $\xi'$ as well.

Comment: It is best not to write $\vee$ in the middle of your sentence.  When I see $(+1) \vee (-1)$, I think it means "the maxumum of $(+1)$ and $ (-1)$."

Comment: @GEdgar.  I edit.... but I do not like that either ....

Comment: An example of the "fix the order" use is the formula $$\sin \theta \pm \sin \varphi = 2 \sin\left( \frac{\theta \pm \varphi}{2} \right) \cos\left( \frac{\theta \mp \varphi}{2} \right)$$ and a lot of similar uses on [Wikipedia: List of trigonometric identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities).